# Shouldn't the visitor pattern be refactored?

Tags: design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Currently I'm working on a project which utilizes the [Visitor Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor). While working with this pattern I found myself writing comments like:

`* @param VisitorInterface $visitor The visitor to visit.`

The visitor pattern consists of the following interfaces:

```
VisitorInterface {
    public function visit($object);
}

VisitableInterface {
    public function accept(VisitorInterface $visitor);
}
```

Now my question: shouldn't it be the opposite?

```
VisitorInterface {
    public function accept($object);
}

VisitableInterface {
    public function visit(VisitorInterface $visitor);
}
```

Because now the visitor will accept something to visit, since a visitor should be something visiting something. While the visitable object will now accept a visitor.

Eg:

```
class Party implements VisitableInterface {
    public function visit(VisitorInterface $visitor) {
        $visitor->accept($this);
    }
}

class Human implements VisitorInterface {
    public function accept($object) {
        // do something with object
    }
}
```

So now we have a party that accepts visitors. These visitors can be asked to accept something from the party to do something with.

I hope to have explained my thoughts on this well enough to show my "concern". Please don't blame me for trying to break a design pattern :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method is called on **object** with parameters, not on parameters. So, if you call `human.visit(party)`, it means that human visits something, and in parameter you specified what - party.